# Order emails not sending, magento 1.9.2.2, Cron heartbeat task error

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, schedule

I have a problem with the Order Confirmation emails not sending, all the others appear to be sending just not the Order confirmation ones.

I've installed AOE scheduler, and it's indicating that there is No Heartbeat task found and asks that I edit my cronab

```
sudo crontab -u new2magento -e
```

and add the following configuration

```
    * * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default
```

as my user name suggests I'm fairly new to magento and could really do with some help finding exactly where I have to add the configuration

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the job on the command line? i.e. `/bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always`

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do that

Comment: do you mean though Terminal?